# How to identify which canvas was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, callback

In the code below there are two canvases clicking on which will open the file browser to open an image. I want to display the opened image in that canvas which was clicked. but

1) the problem is once the control is inside the handleFile I don't know which one of the canvases was originally clicked! how can I do that or how can I pass the canvas as parameter to the function handleFile ?

2)what if I wanted to write something onto textarea1 when clicked on canvas1, write to textarea2 when clicked on canvas2?

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

    <input type="file" id="fileLoader" name="fileLoader" style="display: none" />

    <canvas id="bufferCanvas"></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas1" width="200" height="200" style="cursor:pointer; border:2px solid #000000"></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas2" width="200" height="200" style="cursor:pointer; border:2px solid #ff6a00"></canvas>
    <textarea id="textarea1" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
    <textarea id="textarea2" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
    <script src="upload.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is upload.js

```
var fileLoader = document.getElementById('fileLoader');
var bufferCanvas = document.getElementById('bufferCanvas');
var allCanvases = document.getElementsByTagName("Canvas");

for (var i = 1; i < allCanvases.length; ++i) {
    allCanvases[i].getContext("2d").fillStyle = "blue";
    allCanvases[i].getContext("2d").font = "bold 20px Arial";
    allCanvases[i].getContext("2d").fillText("image " + i + " of 1", 22, 20);
    allCanvases[i].onclick = function (e) {
        fileLoader.click(e);
    }

}

fileLoader.addEventListener('change', handleFile, false);
var textarea1 = document.getElementById('textarea1');
var ctx = bufferCanvas.getContext('2d');

function handleFile(e) {
    // I wanna know what canvas was clicked 
    //So I can display the image on the canvas which was clicked
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (event) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function () {
            bufferCanvas.width = img.width;
            bufferCanvas.height = img.height;
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            dataURL = bufferCanvas.toDataURL('image/png');  // here is the most important part because if you dont replace you will get a DOM 18 exception;
            // window.location.href = dataURL;// opens it in current windows for testing
            textarea1.innerHTML = dataURL;
        }
        img.src = event.target.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `onclick` for the canvas is firing a click for the `fileloader` which has it's own event.  To do what you want you can create global var to hold the `<canvas>` that was clicked.

```
var fileLoader = document.getElementById('fileLoader');
var bufferCanvas = document.getElementById('bufferCanvas');
var allCanvases = document.getElementsByTagName("Canvas");
var clickedCanvas = ''; //<---- will hold the triggering canvas
```

Then in your `onclick` function you can set `html element` to `clickedCanvas`

```
for (var i = 1; i < allCanvases.length; ++i) {
  ...
  ...
  ...
  allCanvases[i].onclick = function (e) {
    clickedCanvas = e.srcElement; // <--- set the clicked on canvas
    fileLoader.click(e);
  }
}
```

Now in `function handleFile(e)` you should be able to get the canvas from `clickedCanvas`

Also I would clear out `clickedCanvas` after you are done so you aren't retaining the last event.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T8HqM/)

Comment: Thanks. what if I wanted to write something onto textarea1 when clicked on canvas1, write to textarea2 when clicked on canvas2?

Comment: You can just check the id of 'clickedCanvas.id' the grab the textarea that you want